# How to make my activity indicator view cover all screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So when a user clicks on a button in my app, I would like to create a new view with an activity indicator and cover the whole screen with it until the button action finishes.

However, my activity indicator view is covering only inside of a table view, it looks like this:

[image]

How to make it cover whole screen? Including the navigation controller and table view toolbar.

Here is my code I use to create the view:

```
self.overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
self.activityIndicator.center = self.overlayView.center;
[self.overlayView addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self.tableView addSubview:self.overlayView];
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change

```
[self.tableView addSubview:self.overlayView];
```

To

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.overlayView];
```

Set the overlay's rect accordingly.

Comment: +1 as this will also rotate properly (shabzco's solution will not).

Comment: @CodaFi Thanks, it worked. But how can I remove the view? Now when I do     [self.activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [self.overlayView removeFromSuperview]; it doesn't work.

Comment: I added my overlay view with a tag: overlayView.tag=1;and then used the tag to identify the overlay to remove it: [[self.navigationController.view viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.overlayView];
```